# How Do I Add More Latest Post To Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I can work pretty good with CSS and HTML but know nothing about PHP. I'm working on a wordpress client project and he wants more than one Latest Post/Recent Post to display on the static homepage. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. From the posted code, can someone show me what to delete and what to replace it with to make 5 of the most latest post appear? I really appreciate everyone's help.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Homepage
 */
?>
<?php $mts_options = get_option(MTS_THEME_NAME); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ($mts_options['mts_banner_show'] == '1') { ?>
<div class="b_first">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="blog_first">
                <!--first content-->
                <div id="first_b">
                    <div class="b_right" <?php if ( isset( $_GET['mailchimp_signup'] ) || !empty( $_GET['aweber_signedup'] ) ) echo 'style="display:none;"'; ?>>
                        <h2 class="front-view-title">
                            <?php echo $mts_options['mts_banner_title']; ?>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="front-view-content">
                            <?php echo $mts_options['mts_banner_texts']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_button_text'])) { ?>
                            <div class="readMore" style="background:<?php echo $mts_options['mts_banner_button_bg']; ?>">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="hide_b();"><?php echo $mts_options['mts_button_text']; ?></a>
                                <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_arrow_image'])) { ?>
                                    <div class="b_dollor">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $mts_options['mts_arrow_image']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--Rightside Content-Option-1-->
                </div>
                <div id="second_b" <?php if ( !isset( $_GET['mailchimp_signup'] ) && empty( $_GET['aweber_signedup'] ) ) echo 'style="display:none;"'; ?>>
                    <div class="blog_first_alternative">
                        <h2 class="front-view-title">
                        <?php echo $mts_options['mts_banner_title']; ?>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="form_wrap">
                            <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_form_image'])) { ?>
                                <div class="form_wrap_left">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $mts_options['mts_form_image']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div class="form_wrap_right">
                                <?php dynamic_sidebar('Home Subscribe Widget'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Rightside content alternative option-->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function hide_b() {
                            jQuery('#first_b').hide();
                            jQuery('#second_b').show();
                        }  
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of first content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="main-container">
    <div id="page">
        <div class="artcl article">
            <div id="content_box">
                <?php if ($mts_options['mts_banner2_show'] == '1') { ?>
                    <!--Second Content-->
                    <div class="blog_second">
                        <div class="b_left">
                            <h2 class="front-view-title">
                                <?php echo $mts_options['mts_social_title']; ?>
                            </h2>
                            <?php if ( !empty($mts_options['mts_banner_social']) && is_array($mts_options['mts_banner_social'])) { ?>
                                <div class="social-icons">
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach( $mts_options['mts_banner_social'] as $header_icons ) : ?>
                                            <?php if( ! empty( $header_icons['mts_banner_icon'] ) && isset( $header_icons['mts_banner_icon'] ) ) : ?>
                                                <li><a href="<?php print $header_icons['mts_banner_icon_link'] ?>" class="header-<?php print $header_icons['mts_banner_icon'] ?>"><span class="fa fa-<?php print $header_icons['mts_banner_icon'] ?>"></span></a></li>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="b_right">
                            <h2 class="front-view-title">
                            <?php echo $mts_options['mts_books_title']; ?>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="b_readings">
                                <ul>
                                    <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_books_image'])){ ?>
                                        <?php foreach( $mts_options['mts_books_image'] as $slide ) : ?>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo $slide['mts_book_link']; ?>"> <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $slide['mts_book_image'], false, array('title' =>'') ); ?></a></li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        <li class="more-books"><a href="<?php echo $mts_options['mts_more_book_link']; ?>"><?php echo $mts_options['mts_more_book_text']; ?><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_featured_posts']) && !empty($mts_options['mts_featured_post_cat'])) { ?>
                    <div class="home_article">
                        <?php 
                        $featured_cat = implode( ",", $mts_options['mts_featured_post_cat'] );
                        $featured_query = new WP_Query('cat='.$featured_cat.'&posts_per_page=5');
                        if ($featured_query->have_posts()) : while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <article class="latestPost featuredpost excerpt">
                            <!--Featured Post-->
                            <header>
                                <h3 class="title front-view-title"><?php echo get_the_category_by_ID($featured_cat); ?></h3>
                                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" id="featured-thumbnail">
                                        <div class="featured-thumbnail">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('steadyincome-featured',array('title' => '')); ?> <?php if (function_exists('wp_review_show_total')) wp_review_show_total(true, 'latestPost-review-wrapper'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </header>
                            <div class="latestpost_wrap">
                                <h2 class="front-view-title">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>
                                "><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </h2>
                                <?php mts_the_postinfo( 'home' ); ?>
                                <div class="front-view-content">
                                    <?php echo mts_excerpt(45); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php mts_readmore(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>

                        <?php $j = 0; 
                        if (get_query_var('page') > 1) { 
                            $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
                        } elseif (get_query_var('paged')) {
                            $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
                        } else { 
                            $paged = 1; 
                        } 
                        $args= array('paged' => $paged, 'post_type' => 'post');


                        query_posts($args); 
                        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                            <?php if($j ==0){ ?>
                                <article class="latestPost latestpost excerpt">
                                    <!--Latest Post-->
                                    <header>
                                        <h3 class="title front-view-title"><?php _e('Latest Post','steadyincome'); ?></h3>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Menu widget article" id="featured-thumbnail">
                                            <div class="featured-thumbnail">
                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('steadyincome-featured',array('title' => '')); ?>
                                                <?php if (function_exists('wp_review_show_total')) wp_review_show_total(true, 'latestPost-review-wrapper'); ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </header>
                                    <div class="latestpost_wrap">
                                        <h2 class="front-view-title">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </h2>
                                        <?php mts_the_postinfo( 'home' ); ?>
                                        <div class="front-view-content">
                                            <?php echo mts_excerpt(40); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php mts_readmore(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </article>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php $j++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: welcome to SO. you take a look at a few things [tour] and [ask]. these should give you a good idea how to ask a good question and get the most out of this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might have some setting in your theme settings. However if you have no setting there.

You can see this line that is limiting latest posts to just one Post:

```
                         <?php if($j ==0){ ?>
```

You may try to change it to number you want to try and see if it loops more posts there:

```
                        <?php if($j < 5){ ?>
```

This should allow the loop to run for five posts now. Give it a try and see if it helps.

Comment: You are amazing! It worked! Such a simple adjustment that I overlooked. Thank you so much! (wish I would of came here hours ago)